# How do I create two table views in one view controller with two custom UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create two `UITableViews` in one view controller using two custom `UITableViewCells`. I have the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomOne") as! CustomOneTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    if tableView == self.autoSuggestTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTwo") as! CustomTwoTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'
```

What do I have to return in the end of the method?

Comment: You need to return something at the end of the method. if `tableView` is not `self.tableView` or `self.autoSuggestTableView`, what does the method return?

Comment: @quant24 That's already covered in the answers.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, I noticed a second too late.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The error appears because if for any reason, the table view is non of the two options that you wrote, then it doesn't have any value to return, just add a default value at the end:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == firstTableView,
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomOne") as? CustomOneTableViewCell {
        return cell
    } else if tableView == autoSuggestTableView,
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTwo") as? CustomTwoTableViewCell {
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

**Updated to swift 4.1.2:**
I've updated this answer to version `4.1.2`, also, because the `return value` of the method cannot be `nil`, modified to a default, dummy `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: If there's only two tables though, how could it be anything other than one of the two tables?

Comment: @ThePumpingLama The function needs a return value, and there's a "road" that doesn't return any value.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, that's right, I think that's a design decision on how do you want to manage any unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @Fantini, there's no need for the second statement to be an if at all, or even or it to be an else. If that's removed then there will always be a return. But anyway my question was directed at rmaddy

Comment: @ThePumpingLama Whether to use `if/else` (my suggestion), one `if` (yours), or the solution in this answer, makes little difference in this simple case. It's more a matter of style than anything in this case. Each of the three solutions are only different in their nuances. Though I actually think the solution in this answer is the best of the three options because it treats the unexpected case of a third table as a problem. The other two options (mine and yours) treats an unknown third table as if it is the second table.

Comment: @rmaddy. What I'm getting at is there won't be  runtime crash. If there is it means the user has changed their entire design and there now no longer two table views, in which case letting it crash is actually good.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama It doesn't necessarily mean a complete change. It could simply be a bug. But that's why I stated that this answer is probably the best. Such a bug will result in a crash forcing it to be fixed.

Comment: @rmaddy we're saying the same thing. I think a crash is good if it detects a change. But your very first comment implies that this answer is not good because there could be a crash, but it seems you are actually saying the opposite of that. That first comment of yours needed an extra phrase at the end to clarify what you  meant by it.

Comment: @Fantini getting a error when i used return nil 
Error:- Nil is incompatible with return type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Well, this was written more than a year ago, so this method now doesn't allow to return `nil` values, so I think that the best approach now is to assign  a default cell type, check @rmaddy 's answer, that should work better than my answer.

Comment: @Fantini I don't know if this ever worked. The return value isn't optional so the line `return nil` should never have compiled. You should fix this answer so it doesn't return `nil`.

Comment: It worked before, but you're right, returning `nil` for this method was never a good idea, now I know., thanks @rmaddy.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath can't return nil

Answer (score 16):

Your issue is that the compiler looks at the possibility that both `if` statements might be false and you don't return anything in that case, hence the error.

If you only have the two tables, the easiest change is this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomOne") as! CustomOneTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTwo") as! CustomTwoTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

My preferred solution to this problem would be to do the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellToReturn = UITableViewCell() // Dummy value
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomOne") as! CustomOneTableViewCell
        cellToReturn = cell
    } else if tableView == self.autoSuggestTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTwo") as! CustomTwoTableViewCell
        cellToReturn = cell
    }

    return cellToReturn
}
```

I think this method maintains readability and clarity whilst also solving the error. I don't like having (dangerous) code written only for compatibility like `return nil`.

Comment: This solution is the best one, in my opinion, since it's also optimal in case you have 2 different Cells in the same TabelViews!

Comment: Just be careful with force downcasting, you don't really know if `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomOne")` will return `nil`, and you neither now if is going to be able to downcast to `CustomOneTableViewCell`. It's better if you use the conditional form `if let cel = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomOne") as? CustomOneTableViewCell`.

Answer (score 4):

If you try two or more than two table in ViewController.then you must be identify tableView in all delegates and dataSource methods. for example

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableView == firstTableView ? first.count: second.count
        //return second.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var returnCell = UITableViewCell()
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = first[indexPath.row]
            returnCell = cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = second[indexPath.row]
            returnCell = cell
        }
        return returnCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Fantini's answer, I would suggest using a switch statement to clean it up a bit:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  switch tableView {

    case firstTableView:
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomOne") as? CustomOneTableViewCell {
      return cell

    case autoSuggestTableView:
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTwo") as? CustomTwoTableViewCell {
      return cell

    default:
      return UITableViewCell()
  }
}
```

Just in case you plan on adding more tableView's later.

Answer (score 1):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var topTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var downTableview: UITableView!
var topData : [String] = []
var downData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    topTableView.delegate = self
    downTableview.delegate = self
    topTableView.dataSource = self
    downTableview.dataSource = self

    for index in 0...20 {
        topData.append("Top Table Row \(index)")
    }

    for index in 10...45 {
        downData.append("Down Table Row \(index)")
    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfRow = 1
    switch tableView {
    case topTableView:
        numberOfRow = topData.count
    case downTableview:
        numberOfRow = downData.count
    default:
        print("Some things Wrong!!")
    }
    return numberOfRow
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    switch tableView {
    case topTableView:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = topData[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    case downTableview:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "downCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = downData[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    default:
        print("Some things Wrong!!")
    }
    return cell
}
```

}