# 2 tableviews in one viewController getting error on tableview.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm having an issue running 2 tableviews - one called 'tableView' and one called 'tableView1', both in same viewcontroller. code loads and runs but when I initiate tableView.reloadData()
tableView1.reloadDate()
I get an error (Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value) If I comment out tableview1.reloadData() the first table runs and loads fine or vice versa. how do I reload both tables together. data is fetched from remote server via Json - offending code snippet below.

```swift
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let countNumberRecordList = JSON_VDICheckFull.response?.dataItems?.numberRecordList?.count ?? 0

        if (countNumberRecordList > 0) {
            return countNumberRecordList
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(30.0)
    }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellRow = indexPath.row


//************************************************//
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberRecordListCell") as! NumberRecordListCell

//**************Getting Error Here***************//

     
        
       cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

  
       cell.fieldDate.text = JSON_VDICheckFull.response?.dataItems?.numberRecordList?[cellRow].dateOfInformation ?? "---"
        cell.fieldSource.text = JSON_VDICheckFull.response?.dataItems?.numberRecordList?[cellRow].sourceOfInformation ?? "---"
        cell.fieldNumber.text = String(JSON_VDICheckFull.response?.dataItems?.numberRecordList?[cellRow].number ?? 0)

        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.layoutSubviews()

           return cell
    }
   

    func tableView1(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let countFinanceRecordList = JSON_VDICheckFull.response?.dataItems?.settingRecordList?.count ?? 0

        if (countSettingRecordList > 0) {
            return countSettingRecordList
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

   func tableView1(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(110.0)
    }

     func tableView1(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellRow = indexPath.row

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SettingRecordListCell") as! SettingRecordListCell

       cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()


   
        return cell

    }
    
       
    }
```

Comment: `func tableView1(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ` that method isn't called, no? It doesn't work like that. or ANY method named `tableView1...` Instead, do `if tableView == tableView1 { // do everything needed for tableView1} else { //It's tableView2 }` in each method of `UITableViewDatasource`/`UITableViewDelegate` you implemented.

Comment: Instead of having one table view delegate method handling two different tables, you might consider moving the table view delegate code into two separate, dedicated, table view delegate objects, one for each table. It’s a better separation of responsibilities, regardless, and minimizes massive view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the answers on this question.

You should first use two different identifiers for your cells and check which table you are receiving in each tableView function.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == firstTableView,
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomOne") as? CustomOneTableViewCell {
        return cell
    } else if tableView == autoSuggestTableView,
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTwo") as? CustomTwoTableViewCell {
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37447124)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to manage 2 table views in a single view controller is confusing. Typically, developers make the view controller serve as the data source (and delegate) for their (single) table view.

If you make your view controller the data source for both of your table views, all the data source methods will be called from both table views, and you have to include logic in all of those methods to say:

### tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) method:

"If I'm being asked about table view 1, return the number of sections in that table view. If I'm being asked about table view 2, return the number of sections in that one."

### tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) method:

"If I'm being asked about table view 1, dequeue a cell using a cell identifier for table view 1, and configure that type of cell. If I'm being asked about table view 2, dequeue a cell using a cell identifier for table view 2, and configure that type of cell."

---

Your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method appears to be written to only dequeue and return one type of cell. It doesn't check to see which table view is asking for a cell. That's wrong.

It might be easier to set up separate objects to serve as the data source for each table view. That way the data source methods don't have to have a bunch of "if table view 1, return data about that table, and if table view 2, return data about the other one" if/else statements. Each data source object can only worry about returning informaion about the table view it manages.